# SQL How to filter where statement with nested AND's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT eventuid
FROM date_contracts dc
WHERE 

        AND (@caseuid = @emptyuid OR dc.caseuid=@caseuid)


        -- date filters

        AND 
        ( 

         (
          @datetype = 0 AND 
          (datestart >= @startdate and dateend <= @enddate)
         )    
         OR 
         (
          @datetype = 1 AND 
          (dc.invoicedate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
         )
         OR
         (
          @datetype = 2 AND
          (dc.recorddate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
         )  
        )
```

I only what to execute the "date filters" when @caseuid = @emptyuid.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

So you want filter when `@caseuid = @emptyuid`

- Then first where `OR` will be `true`.
- Now inner conditional will have ( False or Condition ) so the row only return if `condition = true`  filter is active.
- But if `@caseuid <> @emptyuid`.
- Inner conditional will be ( True or Condition ) mean always `true` and wont filter any row.
- - Also hope `dc.caseuid=@caseuid` otherwise doesnt matter what happen.

.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE 
     (@caseuid = @emptyuid OR dc.caseuid=@caseuid)
 AND 
     (  
       @caseuid <> @emptyuid OR
       (
         @datetype = 0 AND 
         (datestart >= @startdate and dateend <= @enddate)
       ) 
     )
```

**ADD NOTE**

Those query aren't equal

If we have a parameter `@datetype = 0` and a row where

- `(datestart >= @startdate and dateend <= @enddate)` = false (first `OR`)
- `(dc.invoicedate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)`  = true  (second `OR`)

In op version: first `OR` is false because no match `dates`, second and third `OR` are also `false` because doesnt match `datatype` so the 3 `OR` return false.

But in the reduce version:

- `AND @datetype IN (0, 1, 2)` return `true`
- `AND (range1 or range2 or range3)` range2 is true so all 3 OR return true

Comment: @Rahul. I add a note to my question to show why the querys are different. I think your idea was great but I don't see how can replace OP query with a different one  If you see any error in my calculations let me know and I remove my note.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simplify your query like below

```
SELECT eventuid
FROM date_contracts dc
WHERE (@caseuid = @emptyuid OR dc.caseuid=@caseuid)
AND @datetype IN (0, 1, 2)
AND ((datestart >= @startdate and dateend <= @enddate)
OR (dc.invoicedate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
OR (dc.recorddate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate));
```

Comment: I dont think those querys are equals. You can have `true` for `@datetype =1` and  `dc.recorddate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate` here and that doesnt happen in OP query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, looking at the post and the way OP has formed the condition, I think what I suggested should work fine.